# How do I store iterative outputs from an interactive function in R?

Tags: r, function, output, store, interactive

just began using R or any coding language for that matter, and I am stuck on storing the results from multiple iterations of an interactive function.  Each time I iterate back through (I did this with the repeat function), the last output is overwritten.  I realize this is occurring because the function starts over each time and is not iterating like a for loop.  My end state is to have a variable that stores each iteration's results as the user changes the inputs each time through.

```
repeat  # This repeats the future values function questions until you say n or no
{
future_values <<- function() {
  ask <<- readline("Do you want to calculate future account value? ")
  if (substr(ask, 1, 1) == "n")
      return(print("Okay maybe next time.")) 
  else
     FV_input <<- function() {
      months <- readline("How many months into the future do you want to calculate? ")
      months <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(months, ",")))
      m_series <<- months 
      ask2 <- readline("Do you want to calculate future value with interest? ")
      FVwoI <<- (monthlyinvest * months) + TotalValue 
      FVwoI <- format(FVwoI,big.mark=",") 
      FVwoI <- paste("$", sep="", FVwoI) 

      if (substr(ask2, 1, 1) == "n")
          return(print(FVwoI)) 
      else
          rate <- readline("What annual interest rate do you want to use? ")
          rate <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(rate, ",")))
          rate <- rate/100/12 
          rate <<- rate 
          FV_payments <- monthlyinvest * ((((1+rate)^months)-1)/rate)           
          FV_current <- TotalValue * ((1+rate)^months)           
          FVwI <<- FV_payments + FV_current 
          FVwI <- format(FVwI,big.mark=",") 
          FVwI <- paste("$", sep="", FVwI) 
      print(FVwI)
   }
  if (interactive()) FV_input()
}
if (interactive()) future_values()

FVwoI_vector = c()
FVwoI_vector <- FVwoI
FVwI_vector = c()
FVwI_vector <- FVwI

if (substr(ask, 1, 1) == "n")
break
}
```

I tried a few different things, and my final feeble attempt to make this happen is the four lines between the last two if statements.  I got a similar convention to work in a for loop but not with this interactive function.  I apologize if I included too much code here.

Comment: You need `{`s around your last `else` statement.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the response.  The code works fine with or without the {.  Adding the { as expected did not resolve my problem.  I can still only save the last iteration of the output from the user defined inputs.  I would like to be able to save each iteration they do whether they run it it one or 10 times.